# Throwing an exception when two tables contain the same record

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, constraints

The ER schema I am trying to implement calls for two tables:

```
create table enrolled_in (
    student_id number(6) not null,
    course_crn number(6) not null,
    constraint registers_for_pk primary key (student_id, course_crn),
    constraint registers_for_s_fk foreign key (student_id) references student(id),
    constraint registers_for_c_fk foreign key (course_crn) references course(crn)
);

create table registered_for (
    student_id number(6) not null,
    course_crn number(6) not null,
    constraint preregisters_for_pk primary key (student_id, course_crn),
    constraint preregisters_for_s_fk foreign key (student_id) references student(id),
    constraint preregisters_for_c_fk foreign key (course_crn) references course(crn)
);
```

**I must create some sort of integrity constraint that prevents the same record from existing in both tables. That is, a student may not register for a course they are enrolled in.**

My assumption is that I will need to use a trigger because a simple constraint cannot call a UDF (according to the CHECK constraints [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52205)). I am also assuming that I should throw an exception if a duplicate record is found. Here is what I have so far:

```
create or replace trigger reg_duplicate_check
    BEFORE insert on registers_for or enrolled_in
declare
    duplicate_registration exception;
begin
    select * into reg from registers_for;
    FOR r in reg
    LOOP
        -- check for a duplicate record in enrolled_in?
    END LOOP;
    exception
    when duplicate_registration then
        raise_application_error(-20004,'Duplicate record (enrolled_in and registers_for)');
end;
```

I am asking two questions:

1. **Am I on the right track/is this the best way to do this?**
2. **If so, then how can I go about checking for the duplicate records? If not, what is the best way to implement such a constraint?**

I am not able to combine these into one table.

Comment: Can you give an English explanation of what the two tables are used for and what the difference between being "enrolled in" a course and being "registered for" a course and why one would preclude the other and why you cannot use a single table?

Comment: @MT0 yes, you can think of it as pre-registration and registration. Personally, I would combine these into one table, but I am not allowed/able to do that. I was given an ER schema that I must implement, and I cannot combine the tables.

Comment: @MT0 The student should register for a course first, then a faculty member will approve the registration and the record will be moved to the enrolled_in table. I agree, this is a bad design, but I must use separate tables.

Comment: If you add an extra column to each table and a parent table then it's possible to add the integrity constraint you want. However, it seems you don't want to make changes to the model.

Comment: It seems a student's relationship with a particular course follows a lifecycle including enrolment, registration, and perhaps others. Perhaps it would make more sense to have a single table with the current status for each student, and another table showing their history.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson As I've said, I agree with you and everyone else saying that this would be much simpler with a single table. However, I am NOT ALLOWED to combine these into a single table. I MUST implement some sort of constraint on the two tables I described. You are correct about the lifecycle, and you are correct that a status column would be better. The question I asked is how I might implement a trigger that checks for duplicate records and throws an exception.

Comment: @TheImpaler it's not that I don't want to, I can't. I asked my professor if this was acceptable, and he said no. He requires that these tables are separate.

Comment: The solution I pointed out before doesn't involve merging the tables. In fact it can be done adding a third "parent" table (read above). Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answers to your questions:

1. I think you aren't on the right track.
2. You should use only one table, with additional column that says whether that row represents course student enrolled in or registered for. I named it `what_is_it` (line #4) and check constraint (line #11) where E represents "enrolled in", while R represents "registered for". That could also be a foreign key, if you want.

Something like this:

```
SQL> create table student_in_for
  2    (student_id    number(6),
  3     course_crn    number(6),
  4     what_is_it    varchar2(1),
  5     --
  6     constraint pk_stuinfor primary key (student_id, course_crn),
  7     constraint fk_stuinfor_stu foreign key (student_id)
  8       references student (id),
  9     constraint fk_stuinfor_cou foreign key (course_crn)
 10       references course (crn),
 11     constraint ch_stuinfor_what check (what_is_it in ('E', 'R'))
 12    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Doing so, its primary key would prevent two rows with the same [student_id, course_crn] combination.

---

For studying purposes (as you *must* use two tables), then use **two triggers** as well - one for each table. They are very much alike:

```
create or replace trigger trg_biu_enr
  before insert or update on enrolled_in
  for each row
declare
  l_cnt number;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from registered_for
    where student_id = :new.student_id
      and course_crn = :new.course_crn;
  if l_cnt >= 1 then
     raise_application_error(-20001, 'Student has already REGISTERED that course');
  end if;
end;
/

create or replace trigger trg_biu_reg
  before insert or update on registered_for
  for each row
declare
  l_cnt number;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from enrolled_in
    where student_id = :new.student_id
      and course_crn = :new.course_crn;
  if l_cnt >= 1 then
     raise_application_error(-20002, 'Student has already ENROLLED IN that course');
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: I agree with you wholeheartedly. Unfortunfortunately, I am not allowed to combine the two tables into one, as I stated in the original question.

Comment: I believe you should consider that (you, or whoever thought that such a data model is the right way to do it because - in my opinion - it is not). A dummy example: suppose your next task is to take evidence about students' hobbies. Will you create a new table? You could. But then you'll have to develop *everything* that follows - a new form to insert new records (and maintain existing ones), a new report, new *everything*. If you keep information in the same table, you don't have to do a single thing, just allow new (e.g. "H" as "hobby") column value in WHAT_IS_IT column.

Comment: Again....I agree. I would never design it that way; my professor requested two separate tables, and I'm trying to adhere to the assignment specifications. If I could change it, I would. But, I've given up on SO because (even after repeatedly saying that I can't change it, and that I agree) I haven't gotten any suggestions other than to change the schema. I needed suggestions or possible solutions for implementing a constraint, regardless of whether you agree with the design. SO is hopeless sometimes...

Comment: Right; I edited the answer and suggested two triggers. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to combine these into one table.

Create a third table that exists only to enforce the constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE enrolment_registration (
    student_id,
    course_crn,
    type CHAR(1),
    CONSTRAINT enrolment_registration__sct__pk PRIMARY KEY (student_id, course_crn, type),
    CONSTRAINT enrolment_registration__sc__u UNIQUE (student_id, course_crn),
    CONSTRAINT enrolment_registration__t__chk CHECK (type IN ('E', 'R')),
    CONSTRAINT enrolment_registration__s__fk
      FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student(id),
    CONSTRAINT enrolment_registration__c__fk
      FOREIGN KEY (course_crn) REFERENCES course(crn)
);

CREATE TABLE enrolled_in  (
    student_id,
    course_crn,
    type        CHAR(1) INVISIBLE GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('E'),
    CONSTRAINT enrolled_in_pk    PRIMARY KEY (student_id, course_crn),
    CONSTRAINT enrolled_in_sc_fk FOREIGN KEY (student_id, course_crn, type)
      REFERENCES enrolment_registration(student_id, course_crn, type)
);

CREATE TABLE registered_for  (
    student_id,
    course_crn,
    type        CHAR(1) INVISIBLE GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('R'),
    CONSTRAINT preregisters_for_pk    PRIMARY KEY (student_id, course_crn),
    CONSTRAINT preregisters_for_sc_fk FOREIGN KEY (student_id, course_crn, type)
      REFERENCES enrolment_registration(student_id, course_crn, type)
);
```

Then create a triggers to insert/delete/update rows from the child tables with matching rows in the parent table and let the `PRIMARY`/`UNIQUE` keys on the parent table enforce the constraints.

---

Or, just create the child tables and then use a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` to `UNION` them together. Something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE enrolled_in  (
    student_id,
    course_crn,
    CONSTRAINT enrolled_in_pk    PRIMARY KEY (student_id, course_crn),
    CONSTRAINT enrolled_in_s_fk FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(id),
    CONSTRAINT enrolled_in_c_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_crn) REFERENCES courses(crn)
);

CREATE TABLE registered_for  (
    student_id,
    course_crn,
    CONSTRAINT preregisters_for_pk    PRIMARY KEY (student_id, course_crn),
    CONSTRAINT preregisters_for_sc_fk FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(id),
    CONSTRAINT preregisters_for_sc_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_crn) REFERENCES courses(crn)
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW enrolment_registration_mv
   BUILD IMMEDIATE
   REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
AS
SELECT student_id, course_crn, 'E' AS type FROM enrolled_in
UNION ALL
SELECT student_id, course_crn, 'R' AS type FROM registered_for;

ALTER VIEW enrolment_registration_mv
  ADD CONSTRAINT enrolment_registration_mv__sc__pk
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id, course_crn);
```